# Creating a PyCObject pointer in Cython

Tags: python, c, scipy, cython

A few SciPy functions (like `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.geometric_transform`) can take pointers to C functions as arguments to avoid having to call a Python callable on each point of the input array.

In a nutshell :

- Define a function called `my_function` somewhere in the C module
- Return a `PyCObject` with the `&my_function` pointer and (optionally) a `void*` pointer to pass some global data around

The related API method is `PyCObject_FromVoidPtrAndDesc`, and you can read [Extending ndimage in C](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html#extending-ndimage-in-c) to see it in action.

I am very interested in using Cython to keep my code more manageable, but I'm not sure how exactly I should create such an object. Any, well,... pointers?

Comment: +1 just for the pointer joke :-p

Comment: It seemed the right thing to do! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do in Cython the same thing you would do in C, call `PyCObject_FromVoidPtrAndDesc` directly. Here is an example from your link ported to Cython:

```
###### example.pyx ######

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from cpython.cobject cimport PyCObject_FromVoidPtrAndDesc

cdef int _shift_function(int *output_coordinates, double* input_coordinates,
            int output_rank, int input_rank, double *shift_data):
    cdef double shift = shift_data[0]
    cdef int ii
    for ii in range(input_rank):
        input_coordinates[ii] = output_coordinates[ii] - shift
    return 1

cdef void _shift_destructor(void* cobject, void *shift_data):
    free(shift_data)

def shift_function(double shift):
    """This is the function callable from python."""
    cdef double* shift_data = <double*>malloc(sizeof(shift))
    shift_data[0] = shift
    return PyCObject_FromVoidPtrAndDesc(&_shift_function,
                                        shift_data,
                                        &_shift_destructor)
```

Performance should be identical to pure C version.

Note that Cyhton requires operator `&` to get function address. Also, Cython lacks pointer dereference operator `*`, indexing equivalent is used instead (`*ptr` -> `ptr[0]`).

Comment: Thanks for the correct `cimport`s! After a while, I was thinking of importing the functions from the `.h` file and do roughly the same, but I wasn't sure how to handle references and dereferences, so your example clears it all in one stroke ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a bad idea. Cython was created to avoid writing PyObjects also! Moreover, in this case, writing the code through Cython probably doesn't improve code maintenance...
Anyway, you can import the PyObject with

```
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject
```

in your Cython code.

UPDATE

```
from cpython cimport *
```

is safer.

Cheers,
Davide

Comment: You might notice that I wrote **`PyCObject`** and not `PyObject`. A `PyObject` is a normal Python object, while a `PyCObject` is a special `PyObject` used to hold opaque pointers to raw memory addresses. It is used, like I said, by a few functions in SciPy, who just retrieve the function pointer from the `PyCObject` and use it without having the overhead of calling a real Python method. ;)